# We have the equation $2x^2-\sqrt{3}x-1=0$ and have to find $|x_1-x_2|$

Tags: quadratics

> We have the following quadratic equation:
>
> $2x^2-\sqrt{3}x-1=0$ with roots $x_1$ and $x_2$.
>
> I have to find $x_1^2+x_2^2$ and $|x_1-x_2|$.

First we have: $x_1+x_2=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $x_1x_2=-\dfrac{1}{2}$

So $x_1^2+x_2^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2=\dfrac{7}{4}$

Can someone help me with the second one?

I forgot to tell that solving the equation is not an option in my case.

Comment: What is $x_1, x_2$ supposed to be? The roots of the equation?

Comment: @Cornman, edited.

Comment: If you know the sum of the two roots and the difference between them, you're 90% of the way to solving the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluate

$$(x_1-x_2)^2= x_1^2+x_2^2 - 2x_1x_2=\dfrac{7}{4}-2(-\frac 12) = \frac{11}{4}
$$

Thus, $|x_1-x_2|=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$.

Comment: that was pretty ingenuous not gonna lie! good work of vieta's formulas

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you know that, by the Quadratic Formula, $\displaystyle x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, so the difference between the two roots is $\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{3+4(2)(1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{11}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is $\tfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} - \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that: if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\ne0$, if $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$2x^2-\sqrt{3}x-1=0$,

solving, we get: $x_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm\sqrt{3-4\cdot2\cdot(-1)}}{2\cdot2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm\sqrt{11}}{4}$

The required expression, $x_1^2+x_2^2=(\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{11}}{4})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{11}}{4})^2=\frac{3+2\sqrt{33}+11+3-2\sqrt{33}+11}{16}=\frac{7}{4}$.

The second required expression, $|x_1-x_2|=|\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{11}}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{11}}{4}|=|\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{11}-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{11}}{4}|=|\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}|=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$.